# redis-server does not start in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: docker, redis

I upgraded my docker to ubuntu 20.04. Since I did this, the redis-server service does not start in my bitbucket pipeline anymore.

This is all it says

service redis-server start

start-stop-daemon: matching on world-writable pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid is insecure

Starting redis-server: failed

If I run my docker locally and try to start the service, everything works as expected.

I did not find any helpful solutions for the log of the start-stop-daemon, I also tried to delete the pid file before starting the service, but that did not help.

Did anyone have the same or a similar problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

> Redis can be run as a service in bitbucket, you can connect to it
> using localhost. Sample pipeline config provided below

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and Test
        image: node:14.16.0
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
        services:
          - redis
definitions:
  services:
    redis:
      image: redis
```

Comment: this did not work either, but it seems to be an issue with the redisearch module I use for indexing some stuff. Since the update to ubuntu 20.04 the connection gets refused for localhost:

redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.